# How to get all facebook pages of user only for which he/she is administrator of in JS SDK?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Javascript SDK of Facebook Graph API, I want to get all pages of user of which he/she is administrator of. I know the end point for this i.e. me/accounts. But I dont know how to pass here parameter so that API returns Pages of which current user is administrator of.

Comment: There is no way to filter this up-front; you can only sort out the pages the user is not an admin of afterwards on your end. Keep in mind, pages roles have been replaced with page tasks now, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens#page-tasks

Answer (score 0):

You need to request permission [pages_show_list](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-pages_show_list).

Then call the api with request on `link` field

```
GET /me/accounts?fields=link
```

Comment: It does show all pages of user including those for which suer dont have admin rights.

Comment: It shows the pages user `manages`, you might want to take a look at [manage_pages](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-manage_pages) to see if it returns different list, but I don't think there is a way to request list based on fine-grained page roles.